# solr under tomcat can't find contrib folder

Tags: tomcat, drupal-7, solr4

I set up a slightly older version of solr (4.10) under tomcat (7.0.64). And I created a core named 'drupal' and put the 'apachesolr' confs in the core's config folder. Things seem to be working to a point.

But the developer is claiming that indexing still is not working.

And in the solr logs I am finding these warnings:

```
9/9/2015, 6:04:28 PM
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../contrib/extraction/lib (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../contrib/extraction/lib).
9/9/2015, 6:04:28 PM
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../contrib/clustering/lib/ (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../contrib/clustering/lib).
9/9/2015, 6:04:28 PM
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.FloatField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
9/9/2015, 6:04:28 PM
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.DateField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
9/9/2015, 6:04:29 PM
WARN
RequestHandlers
Multiple requestHandler registered to the same name: /update ignoring: org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler
9/9/2015, 6:04:29 PM
WARN
RequestHandlers
Multiple requestHandler registered to the same name: /update/csv ignoring: org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler
9/9/2015, 6:04:29 PM
WARN
RequestHandlers
Multiple requestHandler registered to the same name: /update/json ignoring: org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler
```

In my solrconfig.xml file I have this:

```
  <lib dir="${solr.contrib.dir:../../../contrib}/extraction/lib" />
  <lib dir="${solr.contrib.dir:../../../contrib}/clustering/lib/" />
```

And if I hard code it to the location of the contrib folder, like this:

```
  <lib dir="${solr.contrib.dir:/usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/contrib/extraction/lib" />
  <lib dir="${solr.contrib.dir:/usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/contrib/clustering/lib/" />
```

And restart tomcat, solr can no longer find it's core configuration! I get these errors:

```
9/9/2015, 6:11:42 PM
ERROR
CoreContainer
Error creating core [drupal]: Could not load conf for core drupal: Error loading solr config from /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/conf/solrconfig.xml

drupal: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core drupal: Error loading solr config from /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

These are the files I have in my /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/conf folder, that were copied from apachesolr/solr-conf/solr-4.x

```
# ls -l /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/conf/
total 344
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  1068 Sep  9 16:51 admin-extra.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   928 Sep  9 16:51 admin-extra.menu-bottom.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   926 Sep  9 16:51 admin-extra.menu-top.html
drwxr-xr-x. 3 tomcat tomcat  4096 Sep  9 16:51 clustering
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  3974 Sep  9 16:51 currency.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  1161 Aug 30 15:19 elevate.xml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Sep  9 16:51 lang
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat 78514 Sep  9 16:51 mapping-FoldToASCII.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   507 Aug 30 15:19 mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   186 Aug 30 15:19 protwords.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat    33 Sep  9 16:51 _rest_managed.json
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   450 Sep  9 16:51 _schema_analysis_stopwords_english.json
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   172 Sep  9 16:51 _schema_analysis_synonyms_english.json
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  1594 Aug 30 15:19 schema_extra_fields.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  1977 Aug 30 15:19 schema_extra_types.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat 33748 Aug 30 15:19 schema.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   921 Sep  9 16:51 scripts.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  2395 Aug 30 15:19 solrconfig_extra.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat 62926 Sep  9 18:11 solrconfig.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat 62886 Sep  9 17:37 solrconfig.xml.bak
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   787 Aug 30 15:19 solrcore.properties
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat    13 Sep  9 16:51 spellings.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   280 Aug 30 15:19 stopwords.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat   213 Aug 30 15:19 synonyms.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 tomcat tomcat  1416 Sep  9 16:51 update-script.js
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Sep  9 16:51 velocity
drwxr-xr-x. 2 tomcat tomcat  4096 Sep  9 16:51 xslt
```

This is my solr.xml file:

```
# cat  /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml
<Context docBase="/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/local/tomcat/solr" override="true" />
  </Context>
```

So my questions to you are:

1 How can I get indexing working under drupal for the developer?
2 How can I correctly specify the contrib folder in the solrconfig.xml file?

I used this tutorial to get this far:

[Solr / Tomcat / Drupal Tutorial](http://duntuk.com/how-install-apache-solr-46-apache-tomcat-7-use-drupal)

Thanks!